# How do I call a getter from another store in Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have `vuex` a store `abc.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

const state = {
  recordType: null
};

const getters = {

  recordType: state => state.recordType,

};
.... other code
```

The I have other `vuex` store `xyz.js`:

```
import { API } from '@/api';
import Vue from 'vue';

const state = {
  messages: null
};

const getters = {
  messages: state => state.messages || [],
};

const actions = {
  async openRecord({ dispatch, rootState, commit, state }, record) {

    // api data
    const response = await API.post('api/openrecord/', {
      recordUid: record.recordUid,

      //**** HELP !!! HERE ****//
      recordType: // *** HERE I need to get the recordType getter from abc.js

    });

  }

};
```

> So on `xyz.js` store I need to get the recordType value from `abc.js`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vuex: Access State From Another Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366388/vuex-access-state-from-another-module)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the rootGetters property, along with specifying namespace :

```
rootGetters['abc/recordType']
```

In your case, it gives :

```
const actions = {
  async openRecord({ dispatch, rootGetters, commit, state }, record) {
    // api data
    const response = await API.post('api/openrecord/', {
      recordUid: record.recordUid,
      recordType: rootGetters['abc/recordType']
    });
  }
};
```