# Vuex access a module state while initializing the state of another module

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

Let's say we have a store with two modules, A and B.

All I need is:
Access a state property of A while initializing the state of B.

Accessing that property can be done with 'rootState' if the case was trying to access the property inside a getter, action or mutation.
But how can I do that **while initializing the state**?

Example:

A.js

```
export default  {
   state:{
      x:5
   }
}
```

B.js

```
export default  {
   state:{
      foo: 3+ (how to access A.x here?) // this should be 8
   }
}
```

index.js would look something like this

```
import moduleA from './modules/A'
import moduleB from './modules/B'

new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        A: moduleA,
        B: moduleB,
    },
})
```

Comment: Hey mate, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366388/vuex-access-state-from-another-module) pls

Comment: @NikolaPavicevic I've visited this link before I posted the question but it doesn't help in my use case. It helps when you need to reference other module state in a modules (action-getter or mutation). Because Vuex gives the option of using rootState as a parameter in all these.
What I do need is use that other module state in a module state initialization. Please review the example I supplied.
Thank you.

Comment: have u ever solved this I'm facing the same problem!