# Vue Js - Vuex Store Scenario

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I am working on a Vue JS project and want to ask a conceptual scenario based Question .
So I have 3 modules in the Project.

Module A
Module B
Module C

Each Module has a separate Store . There is one object called Record in each of these Modules. Although each Module in separately maintaining this object (Record) but on the backend (webApi and Services) its a same entity .

Now there is another Module (Module 4) which basically allow user to view and update that object (Record) . And that module in opening in a new window ( i am using vue router- target_blank command to open module object in new tab)

My question is that when the user interacts with that object (Record) in module 4 and change some of its properties , i want other modules to reflect these changes . Currently i need to refresh to update the changes on (Module A, Module B, Module C) .

How can I achieve this ? System is designed to open module 4 in new window and I don't want to change that .

Comment: it makes little sense to duplicate and track the same object across so many different modules.  you should track Record in a single module and other modules can still access/update Record as needed without tracking Record themselves.  All that's needed is to have [modules access the state of other modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366388/vuex-access-state-from-another-module).  Say an update is made in Module 4, Module 4 can access and make direct updates to the states of the other modules if a change needs to be reflected across all modules at the same time.

Comment: You need to either sync multiple app instances through backend (websocket), or use interwindow communication. It depends on your case how this should be done. As for Vuex, there's vuex-broadcast plugin that uses BroadcastChannel to sync a store across windows, could be useful if it works

Comment: @yoduh will it still work if new instance of app is created , because i am opening module in new tab .

Inside Module 4 Action script
const actions = {
  async getRecord(context, payload) {
      console.log( context.rootState); // This gave me states of all other modules i have but somehow record in undefined in rootState Modules .
console.log( context.rootState.ModuleA.record) ; //undefined 
}
Couldnot figure why ? New Instance maybe

Comment: And Seconldy how to commit mutation for rootState . 

Currently for current context
async getRecord(context, payload){
 result= getDataFromApi;
context.commit("setRecord" , result.data);
}

All stores have setRecord Mutation , how to achieve this using rootStates.